# ExtJS 4.2 Toolbar Overflow Items

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, overflow, toolbar

I'm trying to create a toolbar with enableOverflow: true, but if the said toolbar has more than 6 items, I want the toolbar itself to have the first 6 and the latter ones should be shown in the overflow menu, even if it has enough space to show all items normally.

I've tried to find where does it set its width according to the items it has, but with no success and I can't find any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
layout : {
    overflowHandler : 'Menu'
},
```

This will work when there's not enough space for any number of buttons, the toolbar will have as much as it can and the rest will be put in the menu.

**But** if you really want to have only 6 buttons displayed and the rest on a menu, I suggest you try using a 7th button with a [menu](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-menu) config.
[This example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/toolbar/overflow.html) has all you need.

Note there is a difference between a [splitbutton](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.button.Split) and a regular button with a menu: the first will have an action when you click on it and will open the menu only when you click on the arrow, while the other will only open the menu when you click on it. I believe the second is what you want.

Comment: Edit: But if I'm using another menu button, when I resize and the initial 6 don't fit in the toolbar, an overflow will appear containing them and there is the menu button next to it. This would require some 'hacks' on window resize with adding or removing items from the overview and adding them to the menu button and vice-versa. Since overflow is calculated by the items' width, there should be a place where it initially checks each item and then add the overflow, if needed.

Comment: There is a thing like this in the showTrigger function, but it's triggered only if the toolbar is not long enough, therefore there should be a similar function before, but I can't find it.

Comment: I see your point. Could you create a fiddle to help us think about it?

Comment: I would recommend using just the overflow menu and let the buttons use whatever space they have, its just simpler to maintain. If you really need to separate the buttons after 6th,  maybe using overflowHandler : 'Scroll' would fit both requirements.

Comment: It's just like in the example you gave me, only there are normal buttons, no dropdowns and as the width increases/decreases so do the items, basically a normal overview, but I need the extra ones to be in the overflow. I basically repeated what I said earlier, but this is the case. I'm not keen of this idea, but **it's a must based on our internal design**. I've also asked on the sencha forums for guidance to the initial width calculation of the toolbar, but so far no success.

Comment: Basically I want to set the toolbar's width based on the first 6 items if there are more, so the overflow would appear by itself containing the rest. But the only way I managed to do that was by some unorthodox code that made everything based on fixed pixels and that's not good for a project with a big team cause things might get messier than they should be.

Comment: There is an easy alternative, but it will depend on a few things. All the buttons have the same width? Or: can you know beforehand how much the first 6 buttons combined width will be? You could try setting a maxWidth for your toolbar, making it only display first 6 buttons and putting all the rest in the overflow. In this case, you should not use the menu button from my first answer. Then, if your toolbar has enough space only for 3 buttons, the others will be put in the same menu.